# Upgrade OS X Lion to Yosemite with server tools

Tags: macos, upgrade, server.app

I have a Mac running OS X Lion (10.7.5) and it is running server tools with Open Directory serving logins etc.

To update to Yosemite, can I just update to the higher OS X version and then buy the newer Server.app and it will pick up the previous server settings?

I have googled a lot but there doesn't seem to be anything that answers my question clearly. Perhaps because it is as simple as updating OS X and getting the newer tool with nothing else to worry about?